# dropdown box not working?

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

I'm trying to make a car loan calculator with a drop down box. You enter in the amount you would like to borrow, then a dropdown appears with the interest rate at 6.75% or 9.71% . You then type over how many months you would like to repay your loan. However it doesn't seem to be working correctly, it would not gave a result for the two different figures. When is does give the result for the 6.75% the answer is wrong Have I something in my JavaScript wrong? I was thinking i could have it in the wrong order? I have done everything i can think of and its not working?

this is the html

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Loan Amount: €<input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="1000000" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>

<p>Interest Rate:
 <select id= "rate" onchange="computeLoan()">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select A Loan Rate</option>
    <!-- 6.75 loan -->
    <option value="6.75" input id="interest_rate">6.75%</option>
    <!-- 9.71 loan -->
    <option value="9.71" input id="interest_rate">9.71%</option>
</select></p>


<p>Months: <input id="months" type="number" min="1" max="60" value="1" step="1" onchange="computeLoan()"></p>


<h2 id="payment"></h2> 

</body>
</html>
```

javascript

// conditional logic

```
function computeLoan(){

// grab the selected value of the dropdown box 
var r = document.getElementById("rate");
var rateSelected = r.options[r.selectedIndex].value;
var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;

//grab elements by their ID
var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
document.getElementById("interest_rate").value=rateSelected;


//do the maths do find the percentage
var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;

//bring results to two decimal places
var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");


// display the results
document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "Your Monthly Payment = €"+payment;

}
```

Comment: Try using parsInt function before performing any math operations.

Comment: how would i go about that? im new to javascript

Comment: @LearningPhase In this case OP should use `parseFloat`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 thanks the review update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
var interest = (parseFloat(amount) * (parseFloat(interest_rate) * .01)) / parseFloat(months);
```

Comment: where should it be placed?

Comment: Replace your whole line of code "var interest = ..,," with the above code

Answer (score 0):

Replace these line of code in your logic, You must `First convert the string format into numbers and then do the math`.

```
var rateSelected = parseFloat(r.value); // no need of r.options[r.selectedIndex].value
var interest_rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('interest_rate').value);

//grab elements by their ID
var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
var months = parseFloat(document.getElementById('months').value);
```

later when you do your math operations things must work as expected.

Comment: replaced those lines of code and it returns NaN value?

Comment: what is the value of `document.getElementById('interest_rate').value` also this element is not present in your posted HTML..